# Extjs 4.1 Calendar - tooltips not show first time

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I using calendar and in `eventover` function i have create tooltip like

```
                       'eventover': function(vw, rec, el){
                            new Ext.ToolTip({
                                target: el,
                                trackMouse: true,
                                html:   'test'
                            });
                        });
```

But that's not working at first time when i hover an event (I have to hover out and hover it again )

How to fix that thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example showing the issue ? Is this specific to your calendar or more general ?

Comment: Please post more code. `eventover` is not a documented event in ExtJs.

Answer (score 0):

You encounter this problem, because you are creating the `Ext.ToolTip` when hovering the mouse over the element. It then get's displayed on your next mouseover event.

`Ext.ToolTip` is bound to a `target` element and shows automatically when you hover that element. You must create the tooltip **before** you hover the element, and it will show when necessary. Since you cannot attach the tooltip to an element before it is rendered, a good place to define the tooltip is at the `render` event of the `Ext.Component` that contains the element with the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the  `show()` method

```
Ext.ToolTip({
        target: el,
        trackMouse: true,
        html:   'test'
    }).show();
```